# Getting the UTF-8 hex code of a character in clojure

Tags: utf-8, clojure

I can't seem to figure out how to get the UTF-8 hex code for a character in clojure. The closest I got to a relavent result was by trying `(int \Д)`, but it returned `1044` instead of `0414` or `D094`. What would I use to get the latter result?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I didn't exactly make it clear, but I need the UTF-8 hex string, so I need `D094` rather than `0414`. I am going to transform the hex code from `D094` to `_D0_94` for a label printer (I know it's kind of icky - I don't exactly like it myself :P )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just after the constituent bytes:

```
(-> (char 1044) str (.getBytes "UTF-8"))
```

If you want the stringified code, just convert each byte to its hex representation and concatenate them:

```
(defn stringify-bytes [bytes] (->> bytes (map (partial format "%02x")) (apply str)))
```

Comment: The latter is pretty much perfect, but it seems like it's overkill. Is it really that complex to do in clojure?

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment. I read up a bit on UTF-8 and it seems like it was necessary. I ended up adding in the underscores for the printer just before the `apply` call. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'll join in:

```
user=> (format "%04x" (int \Д))
"0414"
```

Comment: That's pretty much it. Is there a way to go from the unicode code point to the utf-8 hex code?

Answer (score 2):

```
user> (Integer/toHexString (int \Д))
"414"
```

Is one option. Doesn't have the leading zero though.